# how to get same element and attribute value in diffrent row in tableview in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know how to do this, but my element name is same prakesh and all attribute name also same so how to get prakesh element attribute value on `tableview` pleases explain me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <prakesh ConfigVersion="1">
        <prakesh ProductId="{ec8e531b-6873-4819-8ade-501f6dc6ff42}" ProductVersion="1.0" ProductLogo="" ProductName="4x6_Glossy" ProductRefImage="4x6_Glossy.png" CustomerType="1" Dpi="300" Unit="0" CoverType="1" CoverWidth="16.5" CoverHeight="12" CoverTopMargin="0.3" CoverBottomMargin="0.3" CoverLeftMargin="0.3" CoverRightMargin="0.3" PageWidth="4" PageHeight="6" PageTopMargin="0.3" PageBottomMargin="0.3" PageLeftMargin="0.3" PageRightMargin="0.3" Comments="4 x 6 Inches" BasePrice="10" PricePerPage="0" BasePriceWithDesign="0" PricePerPageWithDesign="0" FixQuantity="0" Finish="Glossy" ServiceName="Photoprints"/>
        <prakesh ProductId="{6e5b2453-f0e2-43c8-a7d6-1900346b9f83}" ProductVersion="1.0" ProductLogo="" ProductName="4x6_Matt" ProductRefImage="4x6_Matt.png" CustomerType="1" Dpi="300" Unit="0" CoverType="1" CoverWidth="16.5" CoverHeight="12" CoverTopMargin="0.3" CoverBottomMargin="0.3" CoverLeftMargin="0.3" CoverRightMargin="0.3" PageWidth="4" PageHeight="6" PageTopMargin="0.3" PageBottomMargin="0.3" PageLeftMargin="0.3" PageRightMargin="0.3" Comments="4 x 6 Inches" BasePrice="10" PricePerPage="0" BasePriceWithDesign="0" PricePerPageWithDesign="0" FixQuantity="0" Finish="Matt" ServiceName="Photoprints"/>
</prakesh>
```

And done this but I am getting only first prakesh productid and all. How to get second one? Here this is my code:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"Name:%@",elementName);
    _forecastInfo.ProductId = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductId"];
    _forecastInfo.ProductName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"];
    _forecastInfo.ProductRefImage=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductRefImage"];
    _forecastInfo.CustomerType=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CustomerType"];
    _forecastInfo.Dpi=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Dpi"];
    _forecastInfo.Unit=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Unit"];
    _forecastInfo.CoverType=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverType"];
    _forecastInfo.CoverWidth=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverWidth"];
     _forecastInfo.CoverHeight=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverHeight"];



    if(_forecastInfo.ProductId||_forecastInfo.ProductName||_forecastInfo.ProductRefImage||_forecastInfo.CustomerType||_forecastInfo.Dpi|| _forecastInfo.Unit||_forecastInfo.CoverType||_forecastInfo.CoverWidth||_forecastInfo.CoverHeight)
    {
        //[productIdArray addObject:productId];
        [parser abortParsing];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_forecastInfo description]);
        if(delegate)
            [delegate forecastInfoParser:self parsed:_forecastInfo];
        [_forecastInfo release];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Create a globle `NSMutableArray` (let's name it `dataArray`)
- Now initiate it like

  > dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //(Release it if you are using non ARC env.)
- Now in your method:

  ```
  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
   {
       NSLog(@"Name:%@",elementName);
       _forecastInfo.ProductId = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductId"];
       _forecastInfo.ProductName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductName"];
       _forecastInfo.ProductRefImage=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"ProductRefImage"];
       _forecastInfo.CustomerType=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CustomerType"];
       _forecastInfo.Dpi=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Dpi"];
       _forecastInfo.Unit=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Unit"];
       _forecastInfo.CoverType=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverType"];
       _forecastInfo.CoverWidth=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverWidth"];
       _forecastInfo.CoverHeight=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"CoverHeight"];
       if(_forecastInfo.ProductId||_forecastInfo.ProductName||_forecastInfo.ProductRefImage||_forecastInfo.CustomerType||_forecastInfo.Dpi|| _forecastInfo.Unit||_forecastInfo.CoverType||_forecastInfo.CoverWidth||_forecastInfo.CoverHeight)
       {
           //[productIdArray addObject:productId];
           //[parser abortParsing];
          [dataArray addObject:[_forecastInfo copy]];
           NSLog(@"%@",[_forecastInfo description]);
          if(delegate)
              [delegate forecastInfoParser:self parsed:_forecastInfo];
          [_forecastInfo release];
       }
  }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
      if ([elementName isEqual:@"prakesh"]){
          [parser abortParsing];
      }
  }
  ```
- Now populate data in `tableView` using `dataArray`.

Comment: hi friend i am using delegate method so how i can use this array for that  [delegate forecastInfoParser:self parsed:_forecastInfo]; bec where i am display value i am passing in this delegate method       -(void)forecastInfoParser:(ForecastInfoParser*)parser parsed:(ForecastInformation*)forecastInfo
{
    _forecastInfo=[forecastInfo retain];
    [MyTableView reloadData];
}

Comment: If you are using delegate and passing _forecastInfo in that method then you can create array in that class and add content to array obser there.